# Get last_login for all users?

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to get the `last_login` time for all the users but I can't figure out how to do that for a user that isn't logged in.

Is there any way to get this date for user that isn't logged in? or does that `user.last_login` only work for the user that is currently logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last_login` is just a `DateTimeField` stored in the `User` model provided by `contrib.auth`. You can query the `User` objects just like you would any of your own models.

To print out the `last_login` for all users, simply loop through the queryset:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

for user in User.objects.all():
    print user.last_login
```

Alternatively, to get a specific user's `last_login` just query for that particular user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

last_login = User.objects.get(username='bob').last_login
```

The `last_login` field is set whenever the user last logged in (or, if they haven't logged in yet, it is set to the time the user account was created). Regardless, it's always stored in the database so it's accessibility has nothing to do with whether the user is currently logged in or not.